# Installing wordpress into the same directory as existing static html website

Tags: installation, static-website

I have a static html website, located in the public_html directory on my server.  I want to slowly migrate this website, page by page, into wordpress.

It's a big site with around 1,000 pages.  My idea being that I install wordpress into the same public_html directory as the static pages and start with the new index.php page, but have all my other static pages available.  Both the wordpress pages and static pages will have the same nav menu, so to begin, the index.php page will have its first nav link to "page1.html" - so clicking this will take you to the static page1.html page.  Once I have created "page1" in wordpress I can remove the static html page from the server and relink the page in the wordpress nav menu.  And so on for all the pages.

Is this even possible?  It'll take a while to move the whole site onto wordpress, so doing it this way would be preferable, one page at a time.  I just don't know if it can be done.  Any ideas how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any reason why it would not be possible. The main problem I see is updating the nav on the static pages as you move items into WordPress, but setting up redirects may make that easy.

There shouldn't be any complex tasks to get this setup: install WordPress in the same directory as your static files, and that should be it. Confirm that `index.php` is loaded rather than `index.html`, and if so, then you're set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I was under the impression that wordpress "takes over" when you install it .... I dunno, I have a feeling that there will be issues.

Comment: It will take over to some degree (ex: example.com), but if the static files are HTML files (ex: `hello-world.html`), you will be able to link to that file without WordPress interfering (tested). If your static files are in subdirectories, then yeah, you'll probably have some issues, but I think that could be fixed. The best way to find out is to try it.

Comment: Thanks again!  The main 1st level files are in the public_html directory, but there are other sub-directories as well.  of course there are images, css and other usual sub-directories  It's a live and popular site and it is my business - I make my main living from the site so I am a bit scared of simply installing wordpress to check to see if it works or not.  I can't afford any issues or down time.

Comment: In my tests I'm not having any issues with subdirectories either, so it could be rather straight-forward. Would definitely advise testing on an environment that is similar to but definitely NOT your production environment.

Comment: Thanks, great help!